# Excel 2013 interop crash

Tags: vb.net, excel, crash, office-interop, excel-2013

I’m trying to embed Excel 2013 in a vb.net windows forms app.  Through the Interop I instantiate the application, open a spreadsheet and then assign a panel as its parent.  The spreadsheet I am testing with is an empty spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet opens fine but soon after entering a small amount of data Excel crashes.   This works with prior versions of Excel (2010 and down).

Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4763.1000, time stamp: 0x55f7eebf
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4763.1000, time stamp: 0x55f7eebf
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00c2f2c5
Faulting process id: 0x1ed4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1174aa8019193
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: e9a4fbbd-833d-11e5-8883-7ce9d3bf593e

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Public Class Form1
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488

Private Sub btnShowExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowExcel.Click
        Dim sExcelFileName = "C:\book1.xlsx"
        Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application

```
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sExcelFileName)
    oExcel.Application.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    oExcel.Visible = True

    SetParent(oExcel.Hwnd, pnlExcel.Handle)
    SendMessage(oExcel.Hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
```

End Sub
End Class

Comment: To do a little troubleshooting, make a seperate sub and declare --         xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("your.xlsx")
xlsheet1 = xlbook.Sheets("sheet1") xlsheet1.cell(1,1) = "this test" xlBook.close XlApp.Quit ... and see if it works, this will see if its a problem with excel or with what you are sending it

Comment: If that works then try adding --  oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcel.Application.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    oExcel.Visible = True ..... If that works, then all that is left is "SetParent" and "SendMessage"